# Name for type of variable where incrementing it takes you back where you started

Tags: programming-practices

If I have a variable say `x` and set it to `x=2` and then increment it, it happens in some systems that the variable after a number of increments reaches a max value and then resets back to its lowest value. Is there a general name for such a variable? Similar to "counting in a ring" or a modulo count for example

```
x=1
x++ //now x=2
x++ //now x=3
x++ //now x=4
x++ //now x=1
```

Comment: What's wrong with naming it modulo? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division Or modulus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > In mathematics, modular arithmetic is a system of arithmetic for integers, where numbers "wrap around" upon reaching a certain value—the modulus (plural moduli).

From mathematics, [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) a subfield of [Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Example:_Integers_modulo_4) theory.

Answer (score 2):

This behaves like an integer overflow, but as suggested by Daniel Jour in his comment, “[overflow] implies that there's not enough space to store further values”, so this won't be the right term.

I may suggest `CircularCounter`, but I doubt it would be that clear for anyone. I won't use `Modulo` suggested in a comment: when I see a modulo, I expect a division, and I'm lost when I only see addition.

However, I'm not sure there is an exact name for that, simply because the case itself isn't that frequent.

You may have a better luck searching for a name in a context of the domain logic where you need such rule.

Comment: -1 for the "Overflow". This implies that there's not enough space to store further values (have a 5) and also suggests that the result is wrapped, which is not a mandatory consequence of an overflow (though very common).

Comment: @DanielJour: indeed, the suggested term is wrong for the reasons you gave. Thank you for your feedback; I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it a `Cycle`.

Rails already has a view helper method called `cycle` that can essentially do this; you pass it a range or an array of values inside a loop and each successive value is called the next time you loop.

```
<% models.each do |model| %>
    <li class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>"><%= model.name %>
<% end %>
```

The thesaurus adds a few more options:

- sequence
- series
- round